# Removing some point from geom_point ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have some tibble with coordinates called 'coordinates'. I plot these coordinates and I want to have it in points, so for that I use geom_points:

```
coordinates <- tibble(x = x_coords, y = y_coords)
ggplot(coordinates, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

How would I change the geom_point() so that it for example always removes the point from the first coordinate in the plot when for example putting geom_point() + geom_line()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

filter those points from your dataset:

```
coordinates <- tibble(x = x_coords, y = y_coords)

ggplot(coordinates, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(data = coordinates %>% filter(row_number() > 1)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: I probably wasn't that clear in my question, but I meant to like remain the coordinate, but remove the point in the coordinate when putting e.g. geom_point() + geom_line()

Comment: @RoosterRooney see my update. use the `data` argument of a `geom_` layer

Comment: If you want to keep the datapoint for other geom_() calls, use `aes(color = ifelse(x == my_value_x & y == my_value_y, NA, "red"))` for geom_point aesthetics.

Comment: @JackBrookes Thanks for your help! Got it now.